# Create Global Function inside jQuery Event

Tags: jquery, global-variables, uploadify

I have a function that call a POST event for a php script with 2 methods. One is call after `document.ready` to return an Id. The second I want to send that Id for the second method that will find all attach from that Id.

The first method will work but the second does not work. Can I create a global variable from a jquery function event, i.e.,

```
... function(data){
Record=Data; 
}
```

Is this the way to create a global variable?

My code:

```
function getAttachRecords(metodo, id){
    RegId = "";
    jQuery.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        async: true,
        url: "source/getAttchRecord.php",
        data:{method: metodo, id: id},
        cache: true,
        dataType: "html",
        contentType: "application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=ISO-8859-15",
        success: function(data,textStatus,jqXHR){   

            if(metodo ="truncRecord"){  
                RegId = data;           
              $('#file_upload').uploadify({
                'formData'     : {
                            'timestamp' : '<?php echo time();?>',
                            'token'     : '<?php echo md5("unique_salt" . $timestamp);?>',
                            'registo'   : RegId             
                        },
                'uploader'  : 'source/uploadify/upload.php',
                'swf'      : 'source/uploadify/uploadify.swf',
                'script'    : 'source/uploadify/upload.php',
                'cancelImg' : 'source/uploadify/cancel.png',
                'folder'    : 'source/uploadify/uploads',
                'auto'      : true,
                'onSelect': function(){
                                    $("#table_content").slideUp();
                                },
                'onQueueComplete' : function() {
                                    $("#table_content").slideDown();
                                    getAttachRecords("getAttachRecords", RegId);  


                                }
              });
            }else{
                alert(data);
                $("table").find("#table_content").html(data);
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: `window.myfunction = function(){ ... }` or `window.myvar = 'foo'`

Comment: You can _access_ a variable defined in an outer scope that was previously defined. You'll have timing issues, though.

Comment: What you are currently doing creates a global variable named `RegId`. However, you are most likely running into a timing problem because that variable will not contain a value until the ajax request completes.

Answer (score 3):

`window` should always be in scope, so just add your variable off of that:

```
//alert(bar); // `foo` is undefined up here

(function(){
  (function(){
    (function(){
      // some nested scope
      window.foo = 'bar';
    })();
  })();
})();

alert(foo); // `foo` now contains 'bar'
```

Just be careful though because (esp with ajax) it's not guaranteed to be available when you go to use it, so better of checking it, too:

```
if (typeof foo !== 'undefined'){
  alert(foo);
}
```

However, you can also define it before you're within that scope, too:

```
var foo;

(function(){
  (function(){
    (function(){
      // some nested scope
      foo = 'baz';
    })();
  })();
})();

alert(foo); // 'baz'
```

Comment: i have found the problem >if(metodo ="truncRecord"){

Answer (score 1):

Just define it initally outside of the callback or other wrapping function:

```
var Record;

function getNewRecord () {
   Record = 'new data';
}
```

That said if the value is set by a callback you will have no way to determine when this value is updated other than from within the success function or triggering some other event/callback.

Answer (score 0):

i have found the problem

> if(metodo ="truncRecord"){

this if statement is wrong it should be:

> if(metodo =="truncRecord"){

After change it, everything worked fine